# Why is google analytics setting an obsolete cookie when I have entered the correct code?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I have a shopify website and I have added the tracking code that was provided on google analytics website. This was entered and the cookies that are showing up are :

_ga
_gat
_gid
_gat_UA-

The first 3 are correct according to their updated document that lists the cookies that should be implemented.

The last cookie should in fact be *gac* and not _gat_UA-

Google Document can be found here : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

Does anyone know why this would occur?

Answer (score 0):

Check out if the cookie name has an override like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
'cookieName': 'gaCookie',
'cookieDomain': 'blog.example.co.uk',
'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28  // Time in seconds.
});
```

see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id

Or maybe on old cookie? sure it's a new one?